# All pairs of numbers between 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations

I am trying to get all pairs of numbers between two arrays using numpy without success.
Basically what I need is an outer product where the numbers instead of being multiplied are put in an array, i.e.:

```
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])

np.Func(a, b)
>>> [[[1,3], [1,4]]
     [[2,3], [2,4]]]
```

I am trying `np.meshgrid(a,b)` but the output is not what I expect.

Comment: You should update the question with the output you are getting instead of the output you expect.

Comment: I do't know the function to use, I cannot post its output. I have tried meshgrid and its output is not what I expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also take the [`transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy.transpose) of the meshgrid:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.meshgrid(a, b))
array([[[1, 3],
        [1, 4]],

       [[2, 3],
        [2, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack) after doing [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
>>> a, b = np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])
>>> xs, ys = np.meshgrid(a, b)
>>> np.dstack([xs, ys])
array([[[1, 3],
        [2, 3]],

       [[1, 4],
        [2, 4]]])
```

To have the same order as you have shown in the question, you may use [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
>>> np.dstack([xs, ys]).transpose((1, 0, 2))
array([[[1, 3],
        [1, 4]],

       [[2, 3],
        [2, 4]]])
```